# how to get the self-reported location info from a list of twitter usernames?

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

I have a list of twitter usernames in excel format (i.e., 'twitter_usernames.xlsx). I would like to look up the self-reported location (NOT geolocation) info for each twitter user on the list through python 3.7.

I have written some python codes that can look up the location for just one user. I don't know how to iterate the process to find the location information for all users on the list. Can someone help with this problem? Thanks!

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =pd.read_excel('twitter_usernames.xlsx', index_col=None)

consumer_key = 'XYZ'
consumer_secret = 'XYZ'
oauth_token = 'XYZ'
oauth_token_secret = 'XYZ'

def get_user_details(username):
        userobj = api.get_user(username)
        return userobj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #authenticating the app (https://apps.twitter.com/)
    auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

# I don't know how to iterate the process to look for all usernames, so the codes below must be wrong. 

    userOBJ = get_user_details(df['username'])
    print(userOBJ.location)
```

I got the error message below.

```
TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-487aeb790f57> in <module>
      7     #for list of usernames, put them in iterable and call the function
      8 
----> 9     userOBJ = get_user_details(df['username'])
     10     print(userOBJ.location)

<ipython-input-19-c472cfca6014> in get_user_details(username)
      1 def get_user_details(username):
----> 2         userobj = api.get_user(username)
      3         return userobj

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py in _call(*args, **kwargs)
    248                 return method
    249             else:
--> 250                 return method.execute()
    251         finally:
    252             method.session.close()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py in execute(self)
    231                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
    232                 else:
--> 233                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    234 
    235             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]
```

Comment: try calling `[get_user_details(username) for username in df['username']]`

Comment: You're welcome. The term to search for, if you want to learn more about it, is "list comprehension"